# AWS MQ: mq.t3.micro production deployments of RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

Is it possible to create an active/standby or cluster deployment of the AWS MQ managed RabbitMQ service, but using a mq.t3.micro instance size?

I need to deploy the service in production, and want to follow a high availability and redundant architecture, but am not willing to pay the $400+ for the active/standby or cluster deployment of AWS MQ using the mq.m5.large instances.

All of the examples that I have seen make use of the m5 large, and it seems that AWS pushes one to make use of those instances in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mq.t3.micro` instance type does not support cluster deployment in case of RabbitMQ. The minimum instance type required is `mq.m5.large` for RabbitMQ cluster deployment, however, the single instance broker deployment supports `mq.t3.micro`.

Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/broker-instance-types.html#rabbitmq-broker-instance-types) for supported instance types.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any clue about the active/standby deployment type?

Comment: As far I can see in the console, we can choose `mq.t3.micro` for ActiveMQ broker. I did create with this instance type for ActiveMQ Active/Standby deployment mode. But I don't see any option for RabbitMQ.